# Getting a "still reachable" in LEAK SUMMARY in Valgrind when using std::ios::sync_with_stdio(fasle) to print out

Tags: c++

Consider the simple code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void print_vector( const std::vector<int> &inputVector )
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    for ( const int &p : inputVector )
    {
        std::cout << p << "  ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> s{ 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3 };

    std::sort( s.begin(), s.end(), [](const int &a, const int &b)
    {
        return a > b;
    });

    print_vector( s );

    return 0;
}
```

When using the above printing function I get a "still reachable" in the LEAK SUMMARY when profiling with valgrind.

I used the following for compiling: (gcc version 9)

```
g++ --std=c++17 -Wall sorting_stl.cc -o sorting_stl.o
```

and the following valgrind command

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all -v ./sorting_stl.o
```

The full LEAK SUMMARY at the end:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    still reachable: 122,880 bytes in 6 blocks
         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Removing the  `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` and using `std::endl;`
resolves the error. I don't understand the reason though why this happens, or if it is an error here. Is it a good idea in general to use `std::sync_with_stdio(false);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's fine.](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7055040)

This counts as a "false positive"; some aspects of the standard library deliberately don't do clean-up. [This is one of them.](https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org/msg160316.html)

It's not a leak that'll get worse over time. Don't worry about it.

Ideally Valgrind would be neighbourly and would filter this out, but apparently it's been an issue [for a long time](https://lists.debian.org/debian-gcc/2006/06/msg00165.html).

You can read more about [the various report levels in the Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read this about the meaning of "still reachable" http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost . Not quite an extensive explanation about it. Is it in general the case that "still reachable" is not necessarily a leak?

Comment: @bad_locality Pretty much. I'll usually cast an eye over such reports but my instinct is to treat them as false positives, as they usually are.